# Is the forecasting model I am using overfitting and what is the best place to end training?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting

I am working on a forecasting model for natural gas consumption. I have many exogenous variables and when I train the data with the nnetar model(using R and the forecast packagae), one can specify the number of repeats. As I train the data more, the training error decreases sharply, seemingly an overfitting occurs but the CV test error also decreases but marginally. Since the test error does not increase does this constitute a problem? And looking at the data where would be a good place to end the training?

The error for training is seen on the left side and the test is seen on the right. So for the final model if I stop training around reps:20-40 the test error is around 8.7 and the training error can be as low as 0.3. The errors are in % terms (MAPE).

The training data has 915 points and the test data has 365 points. Obviously I am aiming for the lowest forecasting error but I am wondering if the overtraining might be an issue.

[image]

Comment: If you repeat the same exercise using only a new nodes in the neural network, you should see that the error plots level off at a higher final value, as that model would be too simple and could not overfit. As the number of nodes is increased, the final value on the plots should drop until overfitting occurs, when the final value reaches some minimum and will no longer decrease with increasing model complexity. So one thing to try is multiple models with differing levels of complexity to find this point. You might be able to speed up the determination by using multiple computers over a weekend.